# How to filter JSON Object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I am trying to filter the below JSON object and return an array of objects where the value within the key of 'markdown' contains say "steve" - to do this I suspect I need to convert the object to an  array then filter.

I have tried using `Object.entries`

```js
Object.entries(diagnosisData).filter(item => item === 'steve')
```

as well as `JSON.parse` but think I am barking up the wrong tree.

I'd like to return say:

```js
result = [
  {
    "id": "stevey",
    "markdown": "STEVEY",
    "source": null
  },
  {
    "id": "steven",
    "markdown": "STEVEN",
    "source": null
  }
]
```

Could anyone offer a pointer for me?

Many thanks

```js
JSONdata = {
  "steven": {
    "id": "steven",
    "markdown": "STEVEN",
    "source": null
  },
  "john": {
    "id": "johnA",
    "markdown": "JOHNA",
    "source": null
  },
  "henry": {
    "id": "henryP",
    "markdown": "HENRYP",
    "source": null
  },
  "stevel": {
    "id": "steveL",
    "markdown": "STEVEL",
    "source": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)?

Comment: I think your JSONData should rather be an array of objects, or at least that your list of people should be all in an array. there's no point having properties named after their content...

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there with your `Object.entries(...).filter` approach. However, I'm not sure what you want to filter by - the keys, the `id` values or the `markdown` values?

To avoid confusion, let's say you have an object like this instead:

```js
const data = {
  keyA: {
    id: 'idA',
    markdown: 'markdownA'
  },
  keyB: {
    id: 'idB',
    markdown: 'markdownB'
  }
}
```

Then, just for reference, the `Object.XX` functions yield these results:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(data))
// ['keyA', 'keyB']

console.log(Object.values(data))
// [
//   {id: 'idA', markdown: 'markdownA'},
//   {id: 'idB', markdown: 'markdownB'}
// ]

console.log(Object.entries(data))
// [
//   ['keyA', {id: 'idA', markdown: 'markdownA'}],
//   ['keyB', {id: 'idB', markdown: 'markdownB'}]
// ]
```

So:

To filter by the key, there is no filter needed at all as long as it's a perfect match your are looking for:

```js
const result = data.keyA
console.log(result) // {id: 'idA', markdown: 'markdownA'}
```

If needed a non-exact match though, say for example all keys ending with `A`, you can use `Object.entries(...).filter` (and then `map` to the value):

```js
const result = Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([key, value]) => key.endsWith('A'))
  .map(([key, value]) => value)
console.log(result) // [{id: 'idA', markdown: 'markdownA'}]
```

To filter by one of the properties (`id` or `markdown`), you could use `Object.entries(...).filter`, but since you are then not even interested in the key, you could use `Object.values(...).filter` instead:

```js
const result = Object.values(data).filter(item => item.id === 'keyA')
console.log(result) // [{id: 'idA', markdown: 'markdownA'}]
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you - I amended the question to show the result I was looking for - am looking through the keys (seems like Object.values) is the way to go...

Comment: OK but are you searching in `id` or in `markdown`? That's still not clear to me. And by what criteria? Substring match? Start of string? End of string? Is it case-sensitive or not?

Comment: Just guessing: To search in _both_ `id` _and_ `markdown`, matching start of string case-insensitively, you could use `Object.values(JSONObject).filter(item => item.id.toUpperCase().startsWith('STEVE') || item.markdown.toUpperCase().startsWith('STEVE'))`

Comment: Sorry to clarify - I am looking through markdown - and wanting to return an array of objects that contain the string - eg 'steve'

Comment: then all you need is `Object.values(JSONObject).filter(item => item.markdown.includes('STEVE'))`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
let filterKey = 'steve';
const result = Object.entries(JSONdata).filter(([k, v]) => k== filterKey);
```

and then [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object from a list of key-value pairs:

```
Object.fromEntries(result)
```

An example:

```js
let JSONdata = {
   "steve": {
     "id": "steve",
     "markdown": "STEVE",
     "source": null
   },
   "john": {
     "id": "john",
     "markdown": "JOHN",
     "source": null
   },
   "henry": {
     "id": "henry",
     "markdown": "HENRY",
     "source": null
   },
 };

 let filterKey = 'steve';
 const result = Object.entries(JSONdata).filter(([k, v]) => k == filterKey);
 console.log(Object.fromEntries(result))
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method to get desired result:

```
const result = Object.values(JSONdata).filter((v) => 
     v.id.startsWith(filterKey));
```

An example:

```js
let JSONdata = {
   "steveN": {
     "id": "steven",
     "markdown": "STEVEN",
     "source": null
   },
   "john": {
     "id": "johnA",
     "markdown": "JOHNA",
     "source": null
   },
   "henry": {
     "id": "henryP",
     "markdown": "HENRYP",
     "source": null
   },
   "steveL": {
     "id": "steveL",
     "markdown": "STEVEL",
     "source": null
   }
 }

 let filterKey = 'steve';
 const result = Object.values(JSONdata).filter((v) => 
     v.id.startsWith(filterKey));
 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is: `Object.values(JSONdata).filter(o => o.id === 'steve')`

Or if you do not have the is and want to do it by key:

```
const key = Object.keys(JSONdata).filter(o => o === 'steve');

console.log(JSONdata[key]);
```

Comment: `const key = 'steve'` would be... way easier.

Comment: yes of course, but depending of the needs 'steve' could be a variable

Comment: yeah 'steve' is just a variable.